# Nested Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a display that needs to be a little more dynamic than what I'm use to and can't seem to quite find the answer I need.

```
                        Customer a     Customer b     Customer c    (and so on)
  savings with product a

  savings with product b

  (and so on)
```

I know there will always be a minimum of one in each field.  Someone said use a nested repeater or something. I looked around and couldn't find out how to use a nested repeater. I am on a deadline and can't really play with things until I find something that works.

What asp control should I use to do this? An example would be nice but I just need help in the right direction.

I am using sql but getting the data through link. The data ends up in lists.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Waht is the shape of the data that youe get from database?  and how should you present this infomation, any requiremnets from design, usingg divs, tables?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nested Repeaters are pretty easy. Just throw one in your ItemTemplate, and in the OnItemDataBound event of your main repeater do the following

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
     DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

     Repeater nestedRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("NestedRepeater") as Repeater;
     nestedRepeater.DataSource = getSavingsPerCustomer(row["customerID"]);
     nestedRepeater.DataBind();
 }
```

Where the template of the outer repeater had a customer name and a repeater and the inner one has the different savings

probably incorrect syntax but you get the idea

```
<asp:repeater ID="outer">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <div style="float:left">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
     Customer: <%= Eval(customer)%><br/>
     <asp:repeater ID="NestedRepeater">
          <ItemTemplate>
          Saving: <%= Eval(saving)%><br/>
          </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </div>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

[Similar SO question: Repeater in Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923137/repeater-in-repeater)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is for a datatable, but I found this question while trying to accomplish the same task with objects and I didn't find an answer and thought it would be useful for someone else.

If you are using an object that has nested objects in it, you set the datasource like this

```
DataSource='<%# Eval("ChildDataSourceProperty") %>'
```

I came to this conclusion upon all the other answers seeming too complicated

Here is my full repeater code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="linkGroups" 
              runat="server" 
              DataSource="add your datasource">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <dt><%# Eval("ParentProperty") %></dt>
        <dd>                
            <asp:Repeater ID="links" 
                          runat="server" 
                          DataSource='<%# Eval("ChildDataSourceProperty") %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <p><%# Eval("ChildObjectProperty") %></p>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </dd>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a GridView with AutoGenerateColumns="true".
This will create your collumns based on the Datasource you are binding.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

Consider this class

```
public class A
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

And this code

```
GridView1.DataSource = new List<A>() {
    new A() { Field1 = "a", Field2 = 1 },
    new A() { Field1 = "b", Field2 = 2 },
    new A() { Field1 = "c", Field2 = 3 },
};
GridView1.DataBind();
```

This will generate an HTML Table with to columns named Field1 and Field2 with the corresponding 3 rows. Somthing like this.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope=col>Field1</th>
            <th scope=col>Field2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you change the datasource to another source with differnt columns it will automatically generate the corresponding columns for you.