# is it wrong to use a repeater within a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a list of parents, that have children. I am trying to output this on my website doing the following. It works, but is it right? What is the best alternative?

```
 <ul id="example">
        <asp:Repeater ID="monkey" runat="server" >

        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <span class="folder">
                  <%# GetPlantName((string)Container.DataItem) %>
                </span>

                <ul>
                  <asp:Repeater id="moo" runat="server" DataSource="<%# GetTagList((string)Container.DataItem) %>">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="d" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ReportNo")%>'></asp:LinkButton>                  
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>    
                  </asp:Repeater>
                </ul>      
            </li>        
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
```

Comment: is it wrong to use a loop within a loop?

Comment: Do your requirements dictate the need for one? I'd assume yes...

Comment: It's fine.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923137/repeater-in-repeater/2923162

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested repeaters are acceptable.  Just be careful with things like RowDataBound events.  It's not always *obvious*, especially to junior developers, that these methods are essentially nested loops.  I've seen mistakes like a trip to the database in the nested repeater, which results in a lot of overhead.

Just keep in mind that what you're doing is essentially a nested loop and design code accordingly and it's perfectly fine.

Comment: yeah, I'm aware it's a nested loop and I could just use a for each, within a for each, but that would look a little messy. I've found using a repeater within a repeater makes cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

I hope no

I have a repeater in a repeater in a repeater in a repeater in something :-p

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not wrong! On the contrary, it is what we have to do more often than not.

Sometimes there are better solutions but that always depends on the requirements.

hth,

\ ^ / i l l

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong here at all. You have a list (repeater 1) with a nested list (repeater 2).

Answer (score 0):

Is it wrong? No. It's only 'wrong' (and that's basically a pseudonym for inefficient) if you plan on doing something with a repeater that could be done easier with something else.